# JS shorthand If doing more than one operations

Tags: javascript, shorthand-if

> a==b? do 'x' : do 'y' ;

works fine

how would you write to do two things for example?

```
> a==b? do 'x' and do 'z' : do y ;
```

Comment: The `?` is not a shorthand if statement (well, it is sort of but...) it should be used as an expression i.e. `a = b ? c : d` instead of something like `b ? c() : d();`...

Comment: This shorthand is called the ternary operator. See the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Shorthand is not always Betterhand.

Comment: I agree with @AlexK.. Leave the shorthand to the code compressors. Write code to be comprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comma sounds like what you're looking for.

```
(a == b) ? (x, z) : y
```

`x` and `z` can be variables, in which case their values will just be returned by that expression, or they can be actual operations, and in this case too they'll be evaluated, i.e. executed.

So, if you do:

```
(true == true) ? (alert('Hey'), alert('there')) : alert('Aw...')
```

It'll show 2 alerts, the first showing "Hey", and the second - "there".

Also, it doesn't sound like this is very important to you, but it should be noted that the second expression's value (whatever is returned by executing `y`) will be returned as the result of the complete expression.

Comment: `x` and `z` are variables, not operations. This question is asking how to do one or more operations.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: I'm sure he's following the pseudo code given in the question, where `x`, `y` and `z` are replaced with the desired expressions. Either way, reading variables is an operation too.